# How to exclude a certain word in a regular expression in JMeter?

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm having trouble creating a regular expression for JMeter.
With JMeter I request a list of folders from a server. The server returns XML looking like this:

```
<folder name="\" size="296248" date="1395213548" sub="11" files="6">
    <folder name="My Documents" size="0" date="1395069093" sub="0" files="0" flags="2"></folder>
    <folder name="Sharepoint" size="0" date="1394019070" sub="0" files="0" flags="6"></folder>
    <folder name="folder 1" size="0" date="1395140513" sub="0" files="0"></folder>
    <folder name="folder 3" size="0" date="1395213292" sub="0" files="0" flags="2"></folder>
</folder>
```

I need to get the "name" value of all folders, excluding the root folder itself. So now I have the following regular expression in JMeter:

```
<folder name="([^"]+)" [^>]+></folder>
```

(in the example this returns the folders: My Documents, Sharepoint, folder 1, folder 3)

This works, BUT now comes my problem. I need to exclude folders which have an attribute flags="6" and not all folders have this attribute.
So how would I select the folders like I did above, but EXCLUDING those which contain flags="6". If a folder doesn't have a "flags" attribute, or it's value is anything other than 6, then it should be listed in my variable.

In the example, the folder named "Sharepoint" should NOT be returned.

Thanks for any help!

Best regards,
David

Comment: Check your REGEX here: http://www.rubular.com/regexes/11926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter provides [XPath Extractor](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) for working with XML (and HTML via JTidy) data

A relevant XPath expression to return all folder names would look like:

```
//folder/folder/@name
```

Which will return the following matching variables. You'll be able to use [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) to iterate through them.

```
folder=My Documents
folder_1=My Documents
folder_2=Sharepoint
folder_3=folder 1
folder_4=folder 3
folder_matchNr=4
```

Comment: Hi Dmitri, thanks for your answer. Your suggestion returns the same folders as my regular expression, but the thing is that I need to EXCLUDE folders which have the attribute/value flags="6" (see my original question). Is that possible with XPath Extractor?

Comment: Thanks again Dmitri, I had a look at the XPath Extractor, and I got it working! I now use:
//folder/folder[not(@flags='6')]//@name

Comment: @Dmitri - Maybe you could incorporate David's comment into your answer.  Then, we'd have the answer in a tidy little package.  Cheers!